# Query to return the Target Table of a Snowpipe

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to write a script to retreive the COPY_HISTORY of tables that are target tables for my various pipes, but I can't find a way to start with a PIPE name and return the target table that I need to query.

Preferrably would like to avoid pulling out the pipe definition and regexing through it for the INTO clause.

I could not find a way to do it with SHOW PIPES, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PIPES or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.LOAD_HISTORY.

Comment: I do not have possibility to check it, maybe [OBJECT_DEPENDENCIES](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/object_dependencies.html), where referencing_object_name = <pipe>

Comment: That appears to mostly show view and stream dependencies. I don't see pipes in the list. Good thought though.

Comment: Have you tried SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COPY_HISTORY? I see PIPE_NAME and TABLE_NAME. LOAD_HISTORY does not return the history of data loaded using Snowpipe.

Comment: @CristianScutaru, That does work, if you put it in as an answer, I'll give you the bounty. Funny enough, our Snowflake Agent just got back with a solution that uses that table with `PIPE_NAME IS NOT NULL`. This technically only works for "active" pipes, which is not QUITE what I wanted but fits 99% of what I need for this use case.

Comment: thanks, I added as an answer. And yeah, I know what you mean, I think... Try also to join with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PIPES for more checks. I've seen something like this on the Snowflake Community, but I do not remember where.

Answer (score 1):

Try SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.COPY_HISTORY. I see PIPE_NAME and TABLE_NAME.

LOAD_HISTORY does not return the history of data loaded using Snowpipe.